# Which should I catch: Hyak.Common.CloudException or Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudException?

Tags: azure-sdk-.net

```
catch (CloudException)
```

is now not compiling until I decide!

I upgraded to the new azure sdk and I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yes, I updated to the latest Windows Azure Management Compute library, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute 12.0.0.0, from some very old version.

The *old version* depended on Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.

CloudException was defined there.

The *new version* depends on Hyak.Common and Microsoft.Azure.Common.

CloudException is now defined in Hyak.Common, and the new management library will now throw this one, not the other one.

I have now also done

```
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Dependencies
```

since it seems like I should not depend on them any more